# Grails 3.2.10, la aplicación no se ejecuta

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, grails, groovy

Espero que se encuentren bien. Les escribo porque estoy teniendo problemas al ejecutar mi aplicación de Grails y necesito su ayuda para resolverlo.

El problema que estoy experimentando es que cuando intento ejecutar la aplicación, me sale un error que dice "Error de compilación en Grails: Error al cargar el archivo de configuración: no se puede encontrar el archivo".

He revisado mi archivo de configuración y todo parece estar bien configurado. Sin embargo, no sé qué más podría estar causando este problema. ¿Podrían ayudarme a identificar y solucionar este problema?

Al ejecutar el comando:
`grails run-app`

Intenta ejecutar la aplicación pero en consola me sale esto...

```
grails> run-app
| Running application...
2023-03-08 13:27:16.626 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@70e0ac
cd: startup date [Wed Mar 08 13:27:10 CST 2023]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at codec.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)

2023-03-08 13:27:16.642 ERROR --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' defined in codec.Application: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframew
ork.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsR
untimeException: Failed to introspect class: class grails.plugins.jasper.Application
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:762)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:372)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:83)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:388)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:375)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
        at codec.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor]: Factory method 'grailsApplicationPostProcessor' threw exception; nested exception is org.gra
ils.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Failed to introspect class: class grails.plugins.jasper.Application
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588)
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.grails.core.exceptions.GrailsRuntimeException: Failed to introspect class: class grails.plugins.jasper.Application
        at grails.core.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.isArtefact(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:129)
        at grails.core.DefaultGrailsApplication.addOverridableArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:772)
        at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.registerProvidedArtefacts(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:310)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.performGrailsInitializationSequence(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:110)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.initializeGrailsApplication(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:93)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.setApplicationContext(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:225)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.<init>(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:77)
        at org.grails.core.artefact.DomainClassArtefactHandler.isDomainClass(DomainClassArtefactHandler.java:130)
        at org.grails.core.artefact.DomainClassArtefactHandler.isArtefactClass(DomainClassArtefactHandler.java:118)
        at grails.core.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.isArtefact(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:125)
        ... 38 common frames omitted


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
| Error Failed to start server (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
grails>
```

Tengo todas estas dependencias en mi archivo `build.gradle`.
Al hacer un build de la aplicación no sale ningún error pero al ejecutar la misma sí.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:$grailsVersion"
        classpath "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-gradle:2.14.1"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:${gormVersion-".RELEASE"}"
    }
}

version "0.1"
group "codec"

apply plugin:"eclipse"
apply plugin:"idea"
apply plugin:"war"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin:"org.grails.grails-gsp"
apply plugin:"asset-pipeline"

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
}

dependencies {
    runtime "org.javassist:javassist:3.17.1-GA"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure"
    compile "org.grails:grails-core"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
    compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    compile "org.grails:grails-dependencies"
    compile "org.grails:grails-web-boot"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:cache"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:scaffolding"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.1.3.Final"
    compile "org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache:5.1.3.Final"
    console "org.grails:grails-console"
    profile "org.grails.profiles:web"
    runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.14.1"
    //runtime "com.h2database:h2"
    testCompile "org.grails:grails-plugin-testing"
    testCompile "org.grails.plugins:geb"
    testRuntime "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-htmlunit-driver:2.47.1"
    testRuntime "net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:2.18"

    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-url-mappings"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-rest"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-codecs"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-interceptors"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-services"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-datasource"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-databinding"
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-async"
    compile "org.grails:grails-logging"
    runtime "mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.17"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.2"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:spring-security-rest:2.0.0.M2"
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:spring-security-ui:3.0.2'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:mail:3.0.0'
    compile group: 'org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', name: 'http-builder', version: '0.7.1'
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:quartz:2.0.13'
    compile "org.grails:grails-plugin-gsp:3.2.1"
    compile "org.grails.plugins:jasper:2.1.0"
}

bootRun {
    jvmArgs('-Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always')
    addResources = true
}


assets {
    minifyJs = true
    minifyCss = true
}
```

Si alguno de ustedes tuvo un problema similar podrían apoyarme, si encuentro como solucioinarlo también lo compartiré.

Cualquier ayuda o sugerencia sería muy apreciada. Muchas gracias de antemano.

Muchas gracias.

Excelente día.

La versión de Grails que estoy utilizando `Grails 3.2.10`.
La versión de Groovy que estoy utilizando `Groovy 2.3.7`.
La versión del JDK que estoy utilizando `jdk1.8.0_202`.

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer tienes problemas con la dependencia de `org.grails.plugins:jasper`, el problema es como ya no han lanzado actualizaciones para varios plugins puede que ya no tienen compatibilidad con la versión de grails que estas ocupando, te recomendaría migrar a la librería de `net.sf.jasperreports:jasperreports` en caso de que tuviera compatibilidad con lo que estas realizando, en otro caso, sería buscar otra alternativa.